# Would a Drobo benefit from TLER (Western Digital) or ERC (Seagate)?

Tags: hard-drive, drobo

Since Drobo's so-called "BeyondRAID" is analogous to a custom RAID 5 implementation, will using a drive with Time-Limited Error Recovery features enabled be of benefit to the Drobo array?  I haven't been able to find any information in the Drobo knowledgebase.

Comment: Have you asked the Drobo's support? They're pretty responsive (at least for me).

Comment: I haven't called, but that's my next step if the folks here don't know.  Like I said, there was nothing about it in the knowledge base.

Comment: Any update on this David?

Comment: No, I haven't followed up yet.  I'll post here when I do.

Comment: bump.  still an issue?

Comment: Yes, insofar as I don't know the answer.

Answer (score 2):

Talked to Netgear and Drobo about a month ago about it. They told us that TLER is supported and we created a quick post about it at http://www.abmx.com/articles/improvements-in-software-raids.